# The problem of fancyhdr and leftmark /rightmark for the bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, fancyhdr

There is the well know problem of empty marks with latex but fortunately there is a hack for the content to appear only once in the header; but for  the bibliography with biblatex, it does not seem to work.

The following is my setting and expose that References appears twice and does not listen to what I enter in 
   `\markboth{WEWFE}{ONWOOQ}`
just before printing it,

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}




    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot{}

    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection...{#1}}{}}
    \renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection...{#1}}}

    \fancyhead[R]{\today \hspace{2ex} \thepage}
    \fancyhead[L]{  \nouppercase{\leftmark}  }
    \fancyhead[C]{   \nouppercase{\rightmark}  }

    \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{KingZengHistoryGuide,
      author        = {Gary King and Langche Zeng},
      title         = {When Can History Be Our Guide?},
      subtitle      = {The Pitfalls of Counterfactual Inference},
      journaltitle  = {International Studies Quarterly},
      volume        = {51},
      date          = {2007-03},
      pages         = {183-210},
      url           = {http://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/counterf-abs.shtml},
      urldate       = {2012-06-05},
      gender        = {pm},
    }
    @article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1008-2849,
      author        = {Jan Wassenberg and Peter Sanders},
      title         = {Faster Radix Sort via Virtual Memory and Write-Combining},
      eprinttype    = {arxiv},
      eprintclass   = {cs.DS},
      eprint        = {1008.2849},
      date          = {2010-09-06},
      pages         = {1-8},
    }
    \end{filecontents}


    \begin{document}

    %\markboth{}{}
    \tableofcontents

    \section{first section}


    Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 


    \subsection{first subsection}



    Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 





    \subsection{second subsection}

    Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 




    \section{second section}

    Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 




    \nocite{*}

    \markboth{WEWFE}{ONWOOQ}
    \printbibliography



    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can pass your marks using `\defbibheading`:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{LLL}{hhh}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection...{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection...{#1}}}

\fancyhead[R]{\today\hspace{2ex}\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{KingZengHistoryGuide,
  author        = {Gary King and Langche Zeng},
  title         = {When Can History Be Our Guide?},
  subtitle      = {The Pitfalls of Counterfactual Inference},
  journaltitle  = {International Studies Quarterly},
  volume        = {51},
  date          = {2007-03},
  pages         = {183-210},
  url           = {http://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/counterf-abs.shtml},
  urldate       = {2012-06-05},
  gender        = {pm},
}
@article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1008-2849,
  author        = {Jan Wassenberg and Peter Sanders},
  title         = {Faster Radix Sort via Virtual Memory and Write-Combining},
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprintclass   = {cs.DS},
  eprint        = {1008.2849},
  date          = {2010-09-06},
  pages         = {1-8},
}
\end{filecontents}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{LLL}{hhh}}

\begin{document}

%\markboth{}{}
\tableofcontents

\section{first section}


Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 


\subsection{first subsection}



Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 





\subsection{second subsection}

Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 




\section{second section}

Paid was hill sir high. For him precaution any advantages dissimilar comparison few terminated projecting. Prevailed discovery immediate objection of ye at. Repair summer one winter living feebly pretty his. In so sense am known these since. Shortly respect ask cousins brought add tedious nay. Expect relied do we genius is. On as around spirit of hearts genius. Is raptures daughter branched laughter peculiar in settling. 

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]